# How do I log out of Gaming StackExchange?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I just registered with this gaming site and I can't find the "log out" button.

How do I log out?

Answer (score 6):

The rightmost button in the menu bar (next to he question mark) is used to access the log out button. Just click that button and a new menu will drop down, and the log out button is in the top right. See below.

[image: logout button]